# How to add an event listener to a certain part (data bar) of a Google Chart's PieChart?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, google-visualization

Sorry if my English is not OK.

I can't figure out how can I add an event listener to a certain part (piece) of a PieChart?

For example, someone hovers over 'Mushooms' and another chart about the Mushrooms is shown.

[here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYm2r.png)
[image]

How can I "EXTRACT" this musrooms piece from the variable `chart`?

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

I don't need the tooltips on hovering. What I need is opening a modal box whith another chart on hovering. Is that possible? I mean is it possible something else to happen on hover instead of showing tooltip?

I've searched the Internet, but all I found is how to customize the tooltip.

Thank you in advance. I appretiate the time devoted to answer.

Comment: [this example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#placing-charts-in-tooltips) shows how to place charts in tooltips -- or you could listen for the [`'onmouseover'` event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#events) and show your own _modal_ -- turn off the default tooltip with --> `tooltip: {trigger: 'none'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an example of using the `onmouseover` event mentioned in the comment...

run the following snippet in *full page* mode, then hover over "Pepperoni" (blue slice)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Pizza');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Populartiy');
  data.addRows([
    ['Pepperoni', 33],
    ['Hawaiian', 26],
    ['Mushroom', 22],
    ['Sausage', 10],
    ['Anchovies', 9]
  ]);

  var dataPepperoni = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataPepperoni.addColumn('string', 'Pepperoni');
  dataPepperoni.addColumn('number', 'Type');
  dataPepperoni.addRows([
    ['Spicy', 2],
    ['Mild', 3],
    ['Hot', 4]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 400
  };

  var tooltip = document.getElementById('chart_div_tooltip');
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (gglEvent) {
    if (gglEvent.row === 0) {
      tooltip.className = 'tooltip';
      new google.visualization.PieChart(tooltip).draw(dataPepperoni);
    }
  });
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function (gglEvent) {
    tooltip.className = 'hidden';
    tooltip.innerHTML = '';
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  height: 320px;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  width: 320px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div class="hidden" id="chart_div_tooltip"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your example helped me a lot. It's better than the example with the tooltips in Google Documentations :)